# I want to print the difference and the common between two files and print the result in the same order of a particular input file

Tags: regex, string, perl, concatenation

**FILE.txt**

```
bolt W X Y Z

blake X Y Z

gatlin A B C

powell X Y Z

carl P Q R
```

**FORMAT.txt**

```
blake X Y Z

gatlin B C

carl P Q R
```

**OUTPUT.txt**

```
bolt W X Y Z

blake X Y Z

gatlin B C

powell X Y Z

carl P Q R
```

Hey hi,I new to perl and I have a question.I have 2 files namely FILE.txt and FORMAT.txt.I want the output data in the form of FILE.txt but i want to replace the data in FILE.txt with the data of FORMAT.txt which are common to both the files i.e. line with blake , gatlin and carl has to be replaced in FILE.txt with the data obtained from FORMAT.txt. The desired output is as shown in OUTPUT.txt. I tried doing this by finding the dfference and common between the two files.

This is my code

```
my %results = ();  
open FILE1, "< FILE.txt" or die "Could not open file: $! \n"; 
while(my $line = < FILE1>)
{   
$results{$line}=1; 
} 
close(FILE1);  
open FILE2, "<FORMAT.txt" or die "Could not open file: $! \n"; 
while(my $line =< FILE2>) 
{   
$results{$line}++; 
} 
close(FILE2);   
open (OUTFILE1, ">>common.txt") or die "Cannot open $outfile for writing \n"; 
open (OUTFILE, ">>diff.txt") or die "Cannot open $outfile for writing \n";
foreach my $line (keys %results) 
{ 
print OUTFILE $line if $results{$line} == 1;
print OUTFILE1 $line if $results{$line} > 1;

} 
close OUTFILE; 
close OUTFILE1;
```

From this code I got the output by concatenating the two files namely common.txt and diff.txt is FINAL.txt

**FINAL.txt**

```
bolt W X Y Z

powell X Y Z

gatlin B C

gatlin A B C

blake X Y Z

carl P Q R
```

But the order in which i am expecting the output as as shown in OUTPUT.txt and not FINAL.txt
Can anyone please help me out with this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that doesn't use a module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my %data;
my @keys_in_order;

# NOTE: FILE.txt must be processed before FORMAT.txt for the
# logic to be correct, (as below).
for my $file ('FILE.txt', 'FORMAT.txt') {
    open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Unable to open $file for reading. $!";
    while (<$fh>) {
        my ($k, $v) = split ' ', $_, 2;
        push @keys_in_order, $k unless grep /$k/, @keys_in_order; 
        push @{ $data{$k} }, $v; 
    }
    close $fh or die "Unable to close $file. $!";
}

for my $key (@keys_in_order) { 
    print "$key $data{$key}->[-1];    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed. :-)   You are merely finding *common and unique* lines from the two files. Some lines may be unique to FILE.txt or to FORMAT.txt and then there are the lines that are common to both files. You stated the problem was to replace in FILE.txt any values in FORMAT.txt that matched on the person's name. Items in a hash come out in a random order, not the order that they were inserted into the hash. My thought was to read the change values in FORMAT.txt into a hash and then open FILE.txt and print either the line as is or print the replace value from FORMAT.txt.

This will also preserve the order of the lines (in FILE.txt).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Inline::Files;

my %format;
while (<FORMAT>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    $format{$k} = $v;
}

while (<FILE>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    print "$k ", $format{$k} || $v;
}

__FILE__
bolt W X Y Z
blake X Y Z
gatlin A B C
powell X Y Z
carl P Q R
__FORMAT__
blake X Y Z
gatlin B C
carl P Q R
```

*The output is:*

```
bolt W X Y Z
blake X Y Z
gatlin B C
powell X Y Z
carl P Q R
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris Charley... Ya i know the logic wasnt correct but that was the closest thing i could think off.And what u have suggested is the correct way i guess. I want to know how to use this Inline::Files ??? I am getting an error like                                                                ""Can't locate Inline/Files.pm in @INC at exp.pl line 4.""

Comment: Thank you Chris it worked fine for me... but how can the code be modified if there is an extra term in FORMAT like "green R S T" which is not present in FILE but i want to add that term in the output at the end.

Comment: can u help me out on this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242557/input-to-the-program-with-all-the-strings-in-an-array-one-by-one

Answer (score 0):

*but how can the code be modified if there is an extra term in FORMAT like "green R S T" which is not present in FILE*

Hello unkaitha

Sorry if Inline::Files confused you. This module just lets you use the 2 files without opening and closing an actual file. It just helps eliminate the opening and closing code to more clearly expose the logic for the program. You would not use this, but instead open FILE.txt, process, then open FORMAT.txt and process.

I had to add a module, Tie::IxHash. It is used to preserve the order of the keys as they are added to the hash, (as you wished).

Chris

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::IxHash;

# this module will order the keys in the order they were added to the hash
tie my %data, 'Tie::IxHash';

open FILE, "<", 'FILE.txt' or die "Unable to open FILE.txt for reading. $!";
while (<FILE>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    push @{ $data{$k} }, $v;
}
close FILE or die $!;

open FORMAT, "<", "FORMAT.txt" or die "Unable to open FORMAT.txt for reading. $!";
while (<FORMAT>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split ' ', $_, 2;
    push @{ $data{$k} }, $v;
}
close FORMAT or die $!;

for my $key (keys %data) {
    my $aref = $data{$key}; # array reference
    print "$key $aref->[-1]";
}
untie %data;
```

Output:

```
bolt W X Y Z
blake X Y Z
gatlin B C
powell X Y Z
carl P Q R
green R S T
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris Charley... but is their any other alternative for these modules????   i am not able to install these modules so i am having trouble arranging these elements in order of how it was stored in the hash.

Comment: @unkaitha Are you sure you can't install the Tie::IxHash module?

Comment: @ Chris Charley i am trying but i am still not successfull in doing that.... so it would be better if u have any alternative for that?????

Comment: @unkaitha If you are using ActiveState's perl, you can type `ppm-shell` at your command window, then `install Tie::IxHash` and it should install it for you. That's what I do. If your Perl is not ActiveState, you would probably need to use the CPAN module, (it comes with perl). I posted a solution, but you should install the module if possible. `perl -MCPAN -e shell` and then, `install Tie::IxHash`.

Comment: ya i am not using active state so i am trying the same command u have recomanded but its its not installing it. will again... Thanks a lot for the solution @ Chris