# input to the program with all the strings in an array one by one

Tags: arrays, perl, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a shell script consisting of so many perl scripts, one of the perl script have to be run with differnt input each time and the value has to be stored in a single file at the end as shown

```
 #!/bin/sh
 .....
 ....
 perl test.pl apple
 perl test.pl mango
 perl test.pl banana
 ... 
... 
....
```

I type these names in command lines by looking at the file generated with these names.

```
**names.txt**
apple
mango
banana
```

OR

```
**names.txt**
    apple    mango   banana
```

**Is their a way in perl or shell which takes each name at a time as an input.**
That is can names.txt be considered as an array and then the perl script take each array value at a time as an input using ARGV or any other means.So that i can have my shell script like

```
#!/bin/sh
     .....
     ....
     perl test.pl names.txt
     .... 
    ... 
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to write perl programs that take input from files is to construct them as follows:

```
while ($line = <>) {

    # do stuff with $line
}
```

If filenames are given on the command line, perl will automatically open them one by one, feeding the lines to your script. If no filenames are given, it will read from standard input.

But if you write your script this way, you won't be able to give it fruits directly on the command line, they will have to be in a file or standard input.

To handle multiple fruit on the same line, your code can do:

```
while (my $line = <>) {

    chomp $line;

    foreach my $fruit ( split ' ', $line ) {

        # do something with $fruit
    }
}
```

Comment: `open FILE2, "<31.txt"; open FILE3, ">>file2.l"; open FILE123, "<names.txt"; my $names; while (my $line=<FILE2>) { if ($line =~ m/**$names**/ig) .... ....   ....  ... `  Here is my code and $names will have to given different inputs taken from names.txt each time.

Comment: Your code goes where I wrote `# do something with $fruit`. Just change the name of the variable from `$names` to `$fruit`. Or maybe you could read all the fruit names first, and put them into an array and use that in your code. I'm just showing you the general way to process a file given on the command line, you can do with it whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, line by line:

```
while read fruit
do
  perl test.perl "$fruit"
done < names.txt
```

Comment: I am new to programming would u please tel me what bash is?? Am i supposed to write these commands in my shell script????

Comment: bash is a Bourne-shell-compatible shell. Use `#!/bin/bash` as your shebang line (assuming that's where bash is) (although this construct might work fine with sh).

Comment: Ya i got that... And do i have to use ARGV[$i] in the place the perl script uses that input given in command line?????

Comment: The lines will be passed to the script one at a time, just as you asked for.

Comment: My code runs when the name is given in the command line but when i use these set of line it gives me undesirable output... According to the output i am getting i feel that the perl script isnt taking the input value it needs to take.

Comment: This answer should work correctly with the version of names.txt that has each fruit on a separate line -- it should be identical to your original script. But it won't work with all the fruits on the same line. The difficulty with allowing that format is what to do with fruits that have spaces in them, e.g. brazil nut.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you for the reply but as i mentioned it isnt giving a desired result.. Is ther a code which can be added in the perl script itself??? And this is just a sample i have given my original file will have single name without spaces.

Comment: @unkaitha What error are you getting? Can you post the code that you use to read something off the command line? To the bash script that was posted, add: echo "$fruit"   above the line where you call perl and see what that displays.

Comment: @Scooter : `open FILE2, "<31.txt"; open FILE3, ">>file2.l"; open FILE123, "<names.txt"; my $names; while (my $line=<FILE2>) { if ($line =~ m/$names/ig) .... .... .... ...` Here is the part of code which reads the input from command line. I am not getting an error but i see that the input is not been taken from the command line and hence prints all the the unwanted things. Like i am using a regex and want the input given in the command line to be used in that regex but that regex part isnt working when used as it has been told to.